# Flask: python object to json triggering error when read by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm trying to pass python dictionaries and javascript objects back and forth as necessary. From similar questions, I've gathered that I need to do this.

Python:

```py
posts = [
{'author':'JL Rowling','title':'Harry Potter'},
{'author':'JRR Tolkien','title':'Lord of the Rings'},
]
```

Javascript:

```js
var jsonPosts = JSON.parse({{ posts }});
console.log(jsonPosts);
```

Likewise, these doesn't work either:

```
var jsonPosts = JSON.parse(posts|tojson);
var jsonPosts = {{ posts|tojson }};
```

The JS error I'm triggering is `TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable`

I got this advice from the following Q/A:

[Python to Javascript JSON objects (Flask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123800/python-to-javascript-json-objects-flask)

[How can I pass data from Flask to JavaScript in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template)

How can I fix this?

Edit: 
I've used answer recommendation and found the following error to be present in the console:

```
VM129:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at about:16
```

Corresponding to

```
let jsonPosts = JSON.parse();
```

It seems that it doesn't have access to `encoded_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *encoded* posts:

```
encoded_posts = json.dumps(posts)
```

That will give you string, which is what `JSON.parse` is expecting.

```
var jsonPosts = JSON.parse({{ encoded_posts }});
```

Comment: I tried this to no success. So I troubleshooted the `JSON` and the issue seems to be there.